# hit the NHL’s media day on Monday to field the usual questions - to field - meaning?

Tags: meaning

Source: http://sports.yahoo.com/blogs/nhl-puck-daddy/alex-ovechkin-spinning-his-instagram-comment-on-russian--ukraine-140054207.html

> Alex Ovechkin of the Washington Capitals hit the NHL’s media day on Monday **to field** the usual questions: “How’s the new coach? What did you think of the players that weren’t invited back? So, about eventually winning that Stanley Cup …?”

What does **to field** mean in this sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a little background to what others have said: This is based on a sports metaphor.

To *field a ball* in a sport such as baseball (which is played on a baseball **field**) is to catch it or chase after and pick it up -- IOW to get hold of it. Fielding balls is a way of practicing this: balls are repeatedly thrown or batted, and you field (chase after) them as quickly and accurately as you can.

From that literal fielding came the idea of catching and handling any number of things that are "thrown at you" -- in particular questions. Someone fires questions at you quickly and you answer them quickly and spontaneously. It's like fielding balls.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this definition from Collins:
[field](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/field) sense 22.

> 22 (informal)
>      a   to answer (a question) extemporaneously
>      b   to deal with; handle   ⇒ "to field phone calls"

Comment: Or http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/field_31, sense 3.